# Simple spring utility project?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-tool-suite

I am using a spring 3 book to learn Spring. But I am using the latest Eclipse for Spring or STS. The book tells 
me to make a spring utility project (screenshot below) or SUP , but I don't see that anywhere in my list
of "items". I tried - projects pane > right click > new > other > wizard: search for utility.

Nothing shows up. So, what is the equivalent of SUP in today's STS eclipse ?

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have installed the spring suite, go to Help->Eclipse Marketplace. Then search for `Spring` and install `Spring Tool Suite (STS)` for whatever version of Eclipse you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on

```
File -> New -> Spring Project
```

wait a bit for it to load completely ... down at the bottom you'll find `Simple Spring Utility Project`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> New -> Spring Legacy Project. In my case, I had to download it.